# Getting javascript mouse position relative to website prefferably without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, mouse-position

I've found this snippet on Ajaxian, but I can't seem to use the cursor.y (or cursor.x) as a variable and when the function is called as such it does not seem to work. Is there a syntax problem or something else?

```
function getPosition(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var cursor = {x:0, y:0};
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
      cursor.x = e.pageX;
      cursor.y = e.pageY;
    } 
    else {
      cursor.x = e.clientX + 
        (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || 
         document.body.scrollLeft) - 
         document.documentElement.clientLeft;
      cursor.y = e.clientY + 
        (document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
         document.body.scrollTop) - 
         document.documentElement.clientTop;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

I'd preffer not to use jQuery UI if possible, since I've always thaught of jQuery and librarys as a bit of an overkill for most JS programing.

Comment: Hurray! There's actually another person who doesn't like JS libraries =D

Comment: `I'd prefer not to use jQuery if possible` ... You cannot begin to imagine what you're missing.  Note that jQuery is not the same as jQuery UI.

Comment: Seems you may be suffering from NIH syndrome http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here . (most) Experienced developer recognize the utility of good libraries and leverage them when indicated. In this particular case, you are just making more work for youself than you know. Good luck with that.

Comment: why buy a porshe when you cannot drive faster then 70?

Comment: @Cory: What are you talking about?

Comment: He is saying metaphoricaly that you don't need a 70kb+ library for trivial tasks

Comment: I am not going to try to convince anybody to use a library.  It's just like me not wanting to use regular expressions.  So what?  There are a billion ways to accomplish any given development task, and libraries are never *needed*.

Comment: jQuery far smaller than 70KB.

Comment: http://www.jslint.com/ is great for the "is there a syntax problem?" part.

Comment: @Bryan I'd say "too great". there is also [JsHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This has always been [difficult to achieve cross-browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position), but this is about as good as you can get...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Javascript Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      window.onload = function() {
        document.onmousemove = function(e) {
          if(!e) e = window.event;

          if(e.pageX == null && e.clientX != null) {
            var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;

            e.pageX = e.clientX
                    + (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0)
                    - (doc.clientLeft || 0);

            e.pageY = e.clientY
                    + (doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0)
                    - (doc.clientTop || 0);
          }

          document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML = e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY;
        }
      } 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <h1>Position: <span id="pos">0, 0</span></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this is how jQuery does it

Answer (score 0):

This snippet must be called inside a mouse event handler, with the event object from the handler.

Comment: Yes I called it like this 
onclick="getPosition(e); anotherfunct();"
(and yes, the variable is used within anotherfunct()

Comment: You need to pass `event`, not `e`.  Also, how are you passing the return value to `anotherfunc`?

Comment: This function does not create a global `cursor` variable.  You need to explicitly pass its return value to `anotherFunc` as a parameter, or modify the function.

Comment: even if I remove the var infrom of cursor (making it a global variable) it still doesn't work, why?

Comment: Are you passing `event` instead of `e`? It works for me: http://jsbin.com/onewe/2/edit

Comment: thank you, it works great! Nice tool for javascript examples btw

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 0):

//edit//Just in case I misunderstood you can not set the mouse's physical position in javascript.

So I found an answer kind of on here so I shall Simply Link to it for study purposes. [Show mouse x and y position with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202118/show-mouse-x-and-y-position-with-javascript)

Edited----Wanted to share what worked for me.

This is a form of the code I found at above link I changed slightly. It seems as though I must put certain things to window.onload.

```
window.onload = function () {
                IE = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false;


    if (!IE) {
                document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
                document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    }
                document.onmousemove = function (e) {mousePos(e);};

                document.onmousedown = function (e) {mouseClicked();};
};


            var mouseClick;
            var keyClicked;
            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseY = 0;

function mousePos (e) {
    if (!IE) {
                mouseX = e.pageX; 
                mouseY = e.pageY;
    }else{
                mouseX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
                mouseY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    }
                return true;
}
```